# $f(x,y) = \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha y}$, $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$. Find the Joint Distribution of X and Y.

Tags: probability-distributions

Full Disclosure: I am a graduate student taking a class in probability. I am working through extra problems in the Hoel, Port and Stone book which has answers in the back of the textbook. I am not doing these problems for homework, merely as a supplement to the Ross Book which I find a bit confusing.

This is problem #7 in Chapter 6:

$$f(x,y) = \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha y}, \qquad0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$$ Find the Joint Distribution of X and Y.

The answer is given as: 
$$F_{x,y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 - e^{-\alpha x} - \alpha x e^{-\alpha y},& 0 \leq x \leq y\\\\
1 - e^{-\alpha y}(1 + \alpha y),& 0 \leq y \leq x\end{cases}$$

I have been struggling to find the proper limits of integration and would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** This works always, when you do not want to mess up with integration limits: Draw a picture, not of $f$ (so do not worry about how $f$ looks) but of the domain on which $f$ lives!

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Stefanos. I remind myself all of the time to draw a picture as it really helps a lot.

I am still unsure on the limits, however, as I am unsure how to add in the constraint. I have drawn the unit square as well as the diagonal to represent y = x. I have tried integrating with dy from 0 to y, dx from 0 to x as well as dy from 0 to y, dx from 0 to y and I just cannot get it to come out right.

Comment: Fix some x and fix some y. No, try to see the limits of the tetrahedron between the lines X=0,X=x,Y=y and y=x. Does it help. Of course the solution conveys that the result will be different depending on whether x<y or y<x. Does it help?

Comment: It is important to fix a x and y and point the area with X<x, Y<y.

Comment: The limits that you suggest, contained within that area, are the ones that I tried initially: x from 0 to x, y from x to y. Upon integration, I get a different result than the answer. When I do this integration, I get ax(exp(-ax) - exp(-ay)). Have I done something wrong or is this simply the same quantity in a different format?

Comment: No, X does not go from 0 to x. It goes from 0 to y for y<x and from 0 to x (indeed) for y>x. You have to determine the tetrahedron I mentioned above. Do not simplify things. If X goes from 0 to x and Y from x to y then you have a triangle....

Comment: I have drawn this out a few times and the area that I can see is a triangle + a rectangle under the curve for y < x, as seen in the following image: [link](http://i57.tinypic.com/wgomtk.png). Integrating this in WolframAlpha to be sure I am not missing something, I see this as my final answer: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+a^2+exp%28-a*y%29+dxdy+from+0+to+y+from+0+to+x++%2B+integral+of+a^2+exp%28-a*y%29+dxdy+from+y+to+x+from+0+to+x+)

Comment: No, false, your function lives above the line x=y, never below. Now, fix x_1 and y_1<x_1 and then (second case) y_2>x_1 to see what happens. But you are above the line x=y, Nothing exists below the line... no, false, correct it.